# Xamarin Forms Center CollectionView content

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a page that looks like this:

[image]

Now I want the content of the CollectionView to be centered. I already tried things to set on HorizontalOptions=Center, but no luck!

Here is the code of that part:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding coinDataList}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid RowSpacing="0" Margin="20,0,20,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Coin}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#00D8FF" FontSize="18"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}" TextColor="White" FontSize="18"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What happens as the number of items grows?  How is it supposed to center that?

Comment: Didn't think about that xD.... Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: just conceptually I don't think you can center content in a scrolling container - just like you can't vertically center a vertical list

Comment: Okay I was lookinga  a CarouselView, but I have a quick question. Is it possible to show for example 3 items at the same time?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't use a vertical list/collection with 2 columns?

Comment: Because below the Coin price I need to display something else that takes up a lot of space, that's why I choose for a horizontal list

Comment: Either keep what you have and give up on centering it, or try a CarouselView with insets so that more than one item is visible at one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `BindableLayout` in conjunction with the `StackLayout` with horizontal orientation. This will not be as performant as `CollectionView`, but from your UI, it looks like you will not be having a lot of items in your ItemSource collection, but you your need UI to be dynamic and evenly spaced and centered when there are fewer items. As the item list grows, the UI will look more like the horizontal list view.

So here is the minimal working XAML which you can modify to fit into your project. For sake of simplicity, I have added everything in the XAML (no code behind), so you can plug this XAML right into the content page and test it out!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:generic="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=netstandard"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Playground.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <generic:List x:Key="SymbolNames" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <x:String>BTC</x:String>
                <x:String>LTC</x:String>
                <x:String>ETH</x:String>
                <x:String>OT1</x:String>
                <x:String>OT2</x:String>
                <x:String>OT3</x:String>
                <x:String>OT4</x:String>
                <x:String>OT5</x:String>
                <x:String>OT6</x:String>
            </generic:List>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="60" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SymbolNames}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**UI when 3 Items:**

[image]

**UI When multiple overflowing items:**

[image]